# Is it possible to convert saga iterator to regular promise?

Tags: generator, es6-promise, redux-saga

I'm building abstraction layer for [keepassxc webextension](https://github.com/mauron85/keepassxc-browser). It's using redux-saga channels to make look [chrome messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) synchronous. It's working (un)surprisingly well. However I want to completely abstract redux-saga, the way it will look like normal function returning Promise.

**tl;dr**

[KeePassXC-browser](https://github.com/mauron85/keepassxc-browser) will be browser extension that will allow retrieving passwords stored in KeePassXC app from the browser.
There are two possible communication protocols: HTTP and NativeClient. So I decided to use typescript interface and depending on communication protocol there will be two classes that implements this interface.

Interface:

```
interface Keepass {
  getDatabaseHash(): Promise<string>;
  getCredentials(origin: string, formUrl: string): Promise<KeepassCredentials[]>;
  associate(): Promise<KeepassAssociation>;
  isAssociated(dbHash: string): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

[First implementation](https://github.com/mauron85/keepassxc-browser/blob/master/src/background/keepass/KeepassHttp.ts) representing HTTP communication protocol is using [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is already Promise based, so implementation is straight forward and 100% conformed to this interface.

[Second implementation](https://github.com/mauron85/keepassxc-browser/blob/master/src/background/keepass/keepassNaCl.ts) representing NativeClient protocol is using redux-saga (effects and channels) to make asynchronous messaging **look like synchronous function call**. It's bit complicated, but works pretty well and covers edge cases, that would be hard to handle any other way, because [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is protocol based on standard input and standard output streams, so request and responses can be interleaved, out of order etc...

**The actual problem** I'm failing to solve, is that second implementation is not implementing interface, because it's generators not Promises.

---

Basically would like to convert (wrap) saga iterator function with function returning Promise. There is nice [co library](https://github.com/tj/co) that basically does this for normal generators. But doesn't seem to work with redux saga.

```
function* someGenerator() {
  const state = yield select(); // execution freeze here when called from wrapper
  const result = yield call(someEffect);
  return result;
}

function wrapper() {
  return co(someGenerator); // returns Promise
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Redux-saga is based on generator functions for special reason - to allow split asynchronous actions to separated yielded parts and manage them from one endpoint, which located at internal saga process-manager. Instead, in general case, Promise is a thing-in-self, and can't be partial executed. In other simplified words, Promises manage control flow in which them are located, and generators are managed by outer control flow.

> yield select(); // execution freeze here when called from wrapper

Your main misconception is to assume that `select` actual perform some async operation. No, it just pauses function `somegenatator` on that point and transfers control to redux-saga engine, which knows that to do with returned value, and maybe state async process (Maybe no - it does not matter)
When process is done, saga engine resumes generator, and passes return value to it.

You can easily see it in source code of `select` (https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js#L139 ). It just returns an object with some structure, which can be understood by saga engine, then engine perform real action, and calls your generator in `generatorName.next(resultValue)` format.

UPD. Pure theoretically, you can wrap it to re-assignable promise, but it's not usable case

```
// Your library code

function deferredPromise() {
  let resolver = null;
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => (resolver = resolve));
  return [
    resolver,
    promise
  ];
}

function generateSomeGenerator() {

let [ selectDoneResolve, selectDonePromise ] = deferredPromise();

const someGenetator =  function* () {
  const state = yield select(); // execution freeze here when called from wrapper
  const [newSelectDoneResolve, newSelectDonePromise] = deferredPromise();
  selectDoneResolve({
    info: state, nextPromise: newSelectDonePromise
  });
  selectDoneResolve = newSelectDoneResolve;
  selectDonePromise = newSelectDonePromise;

  const result = yield call(someEffect);
  return result;
}

return {
  someGenetator,
  selectDonePromise
};

}

const { someGenetator: someGenetatorImpl, selectDonePromise } = generateSomeGenerator();

export const someGenetator = someGenetatorImpl;

// Wrapper for interface

selectDonePromise.then(watchDone)

function watchDone({ info, nextPromise }) {
   // Do something with your info
   nextPromise.then(watchDone);
}
```

Comment: I get the point of generators and redux-saga. The only reason to convert generator to Promise is abstraction. Imagine typescript interface, where all methods returns Promise. One implementation is using http fetch which is already promise based and another implementation is using generators/redux-saga internally, but conforming to interface it should return Promises. That's why my question if conversion from generators is possible (seems so, using co) and if redux-sagas generators are special case that cannot be converted. And if so why. I will add link to project files, to get the idea...

Comment: @mauron85 Library `co` is not about general wrapping generator function in promise. Instead, it just allows to write async/await-like code by yield series, but in this code only what `co`-library does - is to wait yielded promises at top-level. If case of redux-saga, underlying effects functions in generators does not perform any real action, and yield it to up-level, which in case of `co`-wrapping don't perform anything.

Comment: @mauron85 In other words, saga is infinite interrupt-able process, which is not equalent to promise. Okay, let suppose that you wrapped your code in Promise. When is should resolve

Comment: @mauron85 Pure theoretically, you can wrap it to re-assignable promise, but it's not usable case
https://pastebin.com/Vda3hxzu

Comment: I'm clearly missing the higher picture, which is hidden in implementation of sagas. But thank you for directing me to correct path. Leaving this unresolved for the moment. Still looking for clean solution, whatever it might be (eg. abandon idea of common interface...).